# SCPI Queries with question marks throw -110 error

Tags: c, bash, serial-port

I apparently inadvertently changed some setting so all SCPI commands sent to my device that include a question mark throw a -110 (Command Header Error) as documented here:

> -110 Command Header Error - Indicates there is a syntax error in the command. In this case two colons between SENSE and VOLT.Example " :SENSE::VOLT:RANGE 10"

All other commands (when used properly, of course) work fine.
Because of the error, my guess is that there's something wrong with how my computer is sending non-letters?

Note: I'm sending commands using `#echo "READ?" > /dev/ttyS0`.  I still receive a reply using `cat /dev/ttyS0` but I get a beep and error. (Same error occurs in my C code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the solution!
It appears that somehow (perhaps the blue screen I had yesterday on the Windows where I was running my linux VM from) the settings for `ttyS0` were reset so that there was software flow control for sending data but not receiving.  Thus, my transmissions didn't work with either no flow control or xon_xoff.

To fix this, I set no flow control on my external serial device and ran `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -ixon` on the linux box.

Alternatively, I could have set flow control on the serial device to xon_xoff and ran `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 ixoff` on the linux box.